# Possible to refresh site until change with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, automation, navigation

I am a relatively new coder and have been searching around a bit on here and on google before asking but I have come up empty.

I was wondering if there was a way to create a script in say Javascript, and have it refresh a page until there is a change on the page by inputting the page into a string.

Something along the lines of (excuse the soddy psuedo-code but I realise that some functions would need to be written around this):

```
Start

currentPage = webclient.getPage("www.somesite.com")
boolean diff = false
string pageText = currentPage.astext()

do {
   currentPage.refresh()
} until (currentPage.astext() != pageText)

string alert = "Change Found"
string address = "me@somesite.com"
e-mail(address,alert)

END
```

Thanks for any help anyone can offer a new coder on this :)

Comment: I'm not sure to get exactly what you want, but it seems javascript isn't really the language you need for this. You'd better use PHP or Perl, javascript can't email things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP seems better suited for this kind of operation. Here is what I would do:

- Fetch the page content with cURL
- Wait a bit (e.g. 1 min) *
- Fetch the page content again
- Compare both page contents
- e-mail if there is a change and start over anyway

* You don't want to refresh the page as much as your pseudo-code does, as your script would eat a lot of bandwidth and would be most likely to saturate your targeted website.

Do you need code samples ?

EDIT
Here's my working PHP script:

```
<?php
////////////////
// Parameters //
////////////////
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$sleepyTime = 60; // seconds
$recipient = 'xxx@xxx.xx';
$subject = 'Change found';
$message = 'Change found in ' . $url;

////////////////
// Functions  //
////////////////
function fetchWebsiteContent($url) {
    // init curl handle
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    // Tells curl to return the content
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // fetch content
    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    // close handle and return content
    curl_close($ch);
    return $res;
}

////////////////////
// The comparison //
////////////////////
$firstContent = fetchWebsiteContent($url);

// This is an endless checking scope
while (1) {
    // sleep a bit and fetch website content again
    sleep($sleepytime);
    $secondContent = fetchWebsiteContent($url);

    // check if change occured
    if ($firstContent == $secondContent) {
        mail($recipient, $subject, $message);
    }

    $firstContent = $secondContent;
}
?>
```

Helpful ressources:
[cURL manual](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)
[mail manual](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php)

Hope you like it ;)

Comment: Thank you gents, your help for a fledging begginer is appreciated! Also a code sample would be great to start me off!

And in regards to the refresh rate, I am load testing a site at work which purpose is to not let a user into a site until someone is out the other end, and the user would hit timeouts until into the system. I'm new to this project and a relatively new coder so am wanting to automate how we are testing it to contribute a bit more! :)

Comment: Hmm I have also just thought of something, we need to be able to interact with the site in a firefox/ie window past this process (i.e. once the looping has run and the live site grabbed). Is it possible for cUrl to interact with a live webclient instead of an instance on the server?

Comment: I am unsure whether I understand your question or not, but if I'm correct, you would like an interface that allows you to see dynamically change made through a website ? Or click items in the targeted website dynamically ? I can't provide you with a clear answer, but you might be interested about using both JavaScript and PHP. Javascript can dynamically manipulate content and PHP can perform server-side operations, like fetching off-server and distant content. You can use AJAX to communication information between JS and PHP. Good luck !